# Use of indexOf() method in javascript cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

cstart = document.cookie.indexOf(cname+"=");
What is the use of +"=" after cname in the above method ?

Answer (score 0):

Here `cname` seems to be a variable  and with `+` it is contacting the variable and `=`.

So if `const cname='someName'`, the the code

`cstart = document.cookie.indexOf(cname+"=")`  will compile to

`cstart = document.cookie.indexOf("someName=")`

Comment: why we search like this ? Can't we search like cookie.indexOf("someName") only ?

Answer (score 0):

It is searching the cookie index.
Like `a=b`
If you only search for `a` it you may get the wrong result in

`c=abc&a=b`.

Because It will result the first `a` in `c=a (<= here) bc`

So add a `=` to make it search correctly.